# objective-c open database from a folder

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, directory

I have an app that contains top level folder with subfolders in the app's package - not the Documents area.

Here's the structure:

```
Document/  
Library/  
appPackage  
/tmp
```

The folder is visible when you right-click the  and select "show package contents".

The subfolder is in the appPackage and visible at this point.  The subfolder in turn contains multiple folders each with database files with same name

```
appPackage/mainFolder/subFolder_1/app.sql  
                      subFolder_2/app.sql
                      subFolder_3/app.sql
```

I'd like to open one of these databases (depending on user's choice).  Optimal way would be to open the database from the current location rather than copying it to the Documents area of the app.  I am trying to avoid it.

My question is:  How do I tell sqlite3 interface to open the database from one of these paths?

BTW, I am able to access a .txt file in these subfolders - but not sure about database.

All help appreciated.
R/- : Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *myPath = ...;
sqlite3 *db = NULL;
if (SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_open([myPath fileSystemRepresentation], &db) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast response.  For some reason, I thought that the files *have* to be in the Documents folder.